# How could I set data provider of one item renderer of a datagrid column based on another item renderer (of same datagrid but different column)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex3, adobe

I have two item renderers on 2 different columns of a datagrid. Both are combo box. What I am trying to do here is set dataprovider of second combobox based on selection of item in firxt combobox.  But how could I let the second itemrenderer know what is the item selected in first one?

Here is the code

```
<mx:DataGridColumn id="deptCol" headerText="Department" width="300">
<mx:itemRenderer>
 <mx:Component>
  <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center">
   <mx:ComboBox id="cmbBox1" dataProvider="{XML(data).d.@department_description}" />
  </mx:HBox>
 </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>

<mx:DataGridColumn id="deptCol" headerText="Department" width="300">
<mx:itemRenderer>
 <mx:Component>
  <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center">
   <mx:ComboBox id="cmbBox2" dataProvider="{<some DataProvider Based on Selection of cmbBox1> ?? **HOW TO SET IT**}" />
  </mx:HBox>
 </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it to work using indirect technique... Used XML list as data provider and added another attribute at each level named "IsSelected" and defaulted it to 0 (along with unique ids for each level) after the selection from first compbo box I set the corresponding "IsSelected" = 1...Changes made by one item Renderer were thus available to another. Need not to tell one identified the other using unique ids.